# NavigationDrawer RecyclerView selected items change color

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am trying to change the textColor in my NavigationDrawer when item is selected.I am using RecyclerView as my swipe layout. This is based on the tutorial:

http://www.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-getting-started-with-material-design/

Anyone can suggest the solution

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: So you want to change the textColor of the item [View] when selected?. Is it what you want?

Comment: THanks for the quick response 
I want to change the text color, Also if possible need to change that Navigation Drawer Row layout

Comment: set a click listener to your textview in the adapter. Then you may have to write an interface so that your activity knows you have clicked on the textview. Change the color of your textview in the method of your interface and then call notifydatasetchanged.

Comment: Nothing to happen if I set the listener for Textview, This is I added here 

  textview.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_green_light));
                    textview.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);

                    notifyDataSetChanged();

Can you explain me ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Define a static int in NavigationDrawerAdapter class to represent the selected item

In NavigationDrawerAdapter.java

```
public class NavigationDrawerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NavigationDrawerAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    public static int selected_item = 0;
    ...

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        NavDrawerItem current = data.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(current.getTitle());
        if(position == selected_item)
        {
            holder.title.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        }
        else
        {
            holder.title.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        }
    }

    ...

}
```

In FragmentDrawer.java

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getActivity(), recyclerView, new ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, int position) {

            NavigationDrawerAdapter.selected_item = position;
            recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
            drawerListener.onDrawerItemSelected(view, position);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(containerView);
        }

        ...
    }));

    ...
}
```

Comment: Its working fine now, Thanks @charagjn.

but In here I can be see the changes when I return the slider, I couldn't able to see when I click that item, Can you suggest the idea?
Thanks

Comment: edited, put the close drawer after calling notifyDataSetChanged()

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out, how to change text color as well as the color of the entire view.

I've updated your ***FragmentDrawer.java***

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflating view layout
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) layout.findViewById(R.id.drawerList);

    adapter = new NavigationDrawerAdapter(getActivity(), getData());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getActivity(), recyclerView, new ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, int position) {
            view.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
            ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title)).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.material_blue_grey_800));
            drawerListener.onDrawerItemSelected(view, position);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(containerView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

        }
    }));

    return layout;
}
```

What I've basically done is, in the onClick() method of TouchListener.

```
view.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
```

This will change the **background color of the view**

Similarly since *I've reference to the view*, I could get reference to the **TextView** which is used inside layout of Drawer.

```
((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title)).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.material_blue_grey_800));
```

Comment: Yeah its changing but other items should be the previous color nor, If I click the items then it will be changing one by one to the same color, positioned item only need to change nor how to handle this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    .......

     adapter.setOnItemClickLister(new MenuAdapter.OnItemSelecteListener() {

        View selectedView;

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(View v, int position) {

            if(selectedView != null)
                selectedView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.defaultColor));

            v.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.orange));

            selectedView = v;
        }
    });


}
```