# how to change textcolor of selected list item both header and child in expandable listview?

Tags: android, android-studio, expandablelistview

what i need:[image]
the above screen is my drawer.In that expandable listview,if i pressed the "DashBoard" header list i will redirect to dashboard activity.Here,i need "Dashboard" text to be blue color and other text to be black.when i click "Today followups" childview i want "CRM" and "Today followups" text to blue color and others to be black color.
my Navigation drawer activity:

```
    public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected DrawerLayout drawer;
    ExpandableListView expListView;
    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild,listDatachild2;
    List<String> listDataHeader;
    List<String> listDataHeader2;
    public List<Integer> groupImages;
    private NavigationView navigationView;
    ViewStub viewStub;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_testingnavi);

    }

    public void preparedrawer(){
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        navigationView = (NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        expListView = (ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.navList);
         drawer = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();


        setprofileimage();
        prepareListData();

        listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(
                this, listDataHeader,groupImages,listDataChild,drawer);
        expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        expListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView expandableListView, View view, int i, long l) {
                return false;
            }
        });

        expListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {



                //  mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Expanded",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        expListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Collapsed",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

        expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
            View _lastColored;

            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub



                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)
                                + " : "
                                + listDataChild.get(
                                listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(
                                childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();


                return false;
            }
        });
    }
    public void setviewstub(int layout_id){
        viewStub=(ViewStub)findViewById(R.id.view_stub);
        viewStub.setLayoutResource(layout_id);
        viewStub.inflate();


    }
    public void setprofileimage(){

        CircleImageView profilePictureView = (CircleImageView) navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
        TextView Usernamenav=(TextView)navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.Usernamenav);

        final Userloginsession userloginsession = new Userloginsession(getApplicationContext());
        final HashMap<String, String> userlist = userloginsession. isGetuserDetails();
        String first_namee=userlist.get(Userloginsession.IS_FIRST_NAME);
        String last_namee=userlist.get(Userloginsession.IS_LAST_NAME);
        Picasso.with(BaseActivity.this)
                .load(Url.imgurl + userlist.get(Userloginsession.IS_IMAGE))
                .fit().centerCrop()
                .into(profilePictureView);
        Usernamenav.setText(first_namee+" "+last_namee);
        Log.i("imgurl",Url.imgurl + userlist.get(Userloginsession.IS_IMAGE));


    }
    private void prepareListData() {

        groupImages= new ArrayList<Integer>();
        groupImages.add(R.drawable.dashboard_icon);
        groupImages.add(R.drawable.crm_icon);
        groupImages.add(R.drawable.accouns_icon);
        groupImages.add(R.drawable.settings_icon);
        groupImages.add(R.drawable.logout_icon);



        listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
        listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        // Adding child data
        listDataHeader.add("Dashboard");
        listDataHeader.add("CRM");
        listDataHeader.add("Accounts");
        listDataHeader.add("Settings");
        listDataHeader.add("LogOut");

        // Adding child data

        List<String> Dashboard = new ArrayList<String>();

        List<String> CRM = new ArrayList<String>();
        CRM.add("Today Followup's");
        CRM.add("Unhandled Followup(s)");
        CRM.add("Today Appointments");
        CRM.add("Unhandled Appointment(s)");
        CRM.add("Cold Call(s)");


        List<String> Accounts = new ArrayList<String>();
        Accounts.add("Quotations");
        Accounts.add("Orders");
        Accounts.add("Payments");


        List<String> Settings = new ArrayList<String>();

        List<String> Logout = new ArrayList<String>();
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), Dashboard);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), CRM); // Header, Child data
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), Accounts);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(3), Settings);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(4), Logout);

    }
public static void dointent(Context A1, Class A2){

    Intent i = new Intent().setClass(A1, A2);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    A1.startActivity(i);


}
    public  static Typeface settypefacess(Context _context,String fonts){

        Typeface roboto = Typeface.createFromAsset(_context.getAssets(),
                fonts);
        return roboto;
    }

}
```

My adapter:`

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    private Context _context;
    private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
    // child data in format of header title, child title
    private List<Integer> _group;

    private DrawerLayout _drawer;

    private static final int[] EMPTY_STATE_SET = {};
    private static final int[] GROUP_EXPANDED_STATE_SET =
            {android.R.attr.state_expanded};
    private static final int[][] GROUP_STATE_SETS = {
            EMPTY_STATE_SET, // 0
            GROUP_EXPANDED_STATE_SET // 1
    };

    private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;
    ExpandableListView expandList;
    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader, List<Integer> group,
                                 HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData, DrawerLayout drawer) {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listChildData;
        this._group=group;
        this._drawer=drawer;

    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosititon);
    }
    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        int childpositionaa= (int) getChildId(groupPosition,childPosition);
        int gropuposi= (int) getGroupId(groupPosition);
        Log.i("groupposi", String.valueOf(+groupPosition));
        Log.i("groupposicc", String.valueOf(+childPosition));
        Log.i("groupposiccee", String.valueOf(+childpositionaa));
        int child3position=(int)getChildId(1,childPosition);
        Log.i("groupposiccee33", String.valueOf(+child3position));

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }
Log.i("childposition",""+childPosition);
        Typeface roboto = Typeface.createFromAsset(_context.getAssets(),
                "font/Roboto-Light.ttf");
        AppCompatTextView txtListChild = (AppCompatTextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);
        txtListChild.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                        _drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                        switch (groupPosition) {
                            case 0:
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                switch (childPosition){
                                    case 0:
                                        BaseActivity.dointent(_context.getApplicationContext(),Handled_follow.class);

                                        break;
                                    case 1:
                                        BaseActivity.dointent(_context.getApplicationContext(), Unhanded_follow.class);
                                        break;
                                    case 2:
                                        BaseActivity.dointent(_context.getApplicationContext(), Navi_recyview.class);
                                                break;
                                    case 3:
                                        BaseActivity.dointent(_context.getApplicationContext(), Unhandled_appoint.class);
                                                                          break;
                                    case 4:
                                        BaseActivity.dointent(_context.getApplicationContext(), Cold_calls.class);
                                                                              break;
                                }
                                break;
                        }                        
                        break;
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
        AppCompatTextView txtchildcount= (AppCompatTextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblistnavcount);
        txtListChild.setText(childText);
        txtListChild.setTypeface(roboto);


        txtchildcount.setText(myList.get(childpositionaa));
        if(gropuposi==2){
            if(childpositionaa==0){
                txtchildcount.setText(myList.get(5));

            }
            else{
                txtchildcount.setText(myList.get(4));
            }
            txtchildcount.setText(myList.get(childpositionaa+5));
        }
        else{
            txtchildcount.setText(myList.get(childpositionaa));
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this._listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        int headerimg = _group.get(groupPosition);
        Log.i("groupposigroupview", String.valueOf(+groupPosition));
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
        }
        AppCompatTextView lblListHeader = (AppCompatTextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        View ind = convertView.findViewById( R.id.indicicon);

        if( ind != null ) {
            ImageView indicator = (ImageView)ind;
            if( getChildrenCount( groupPosition ) == 0 ) {
                indicator.setVisibility( View.INVISIBLE );
            } else {
                indicator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                if (isExpanded) {
                    lblListHeader.setTextColor(_context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
                    indicator.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_expand_less_black_18dp);
                } else {
                    lblListHeader.setTextColor(_context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorlisthead));

                    indicator.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_expand_more_black_18dp);
                }
            }
        }
        Typeface roboto = Typeface.createFromAsset(_context.getAssets(),
                "font/Roboto-Regular.ttf"); //use this.getAssets if you are calling from an Activity


        lblListHeader.setTypeface(roboto);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);
        ImageView imgsListHeader = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.imagview);

        imgsListHeader.setImageResource(headerimg);
lblListHeader.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                switch (groupPosition) {
                    case 0:
                        _drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                        BaseActivity.dointent(_context.getApplicationContext(),Dashboard.class);
                        break;
                    case 1:

                        break;
                    case 2:

                    case 3:
                        _drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

                        break;
                    case 4:
                        _drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

                        break;
                }
                break;
        }

        return false;
    }
});
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {


        return true;
    }

}
`
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to modify the GroupHeader and GroupItem associated to your **current** position in the hierarchy.

In order to do that, your ListAdapter needs to know what this position is. You can pass that as a parameter to the constructor for example.

Then, when inflating the group header (getGroupView) and group item (getChildView), just set your textview decoration to bold (or inflate another specific layout for selected items) if the item is the "current position" one.

The position of the header and the child are passed as parameters of the getGroupView and getChildView methods.

Please have a look at [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31045563/navigationdrawer-recyclerview-selected-items-change-color) or [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32530315/recyclerview-row-item-selection-color-change) that answer to problems related to yours.

Comment: @thank you w00ly...see in above image if i selected dashboard i want that text to be turn blue color until i select another lists.if i select cold calls then i want CRM and cold calls  text to be blue color and others to be black

Comment: I suppose all your activities extends from BaseActivity.
Well, when clicking on your "Cold Call(s)", you are launching an intent, right ? Here, you pass your selected item as a parameter (your class). You can also pass an id, and when refreshing the drawer, use this parameter to know on which section you are, and do the modifications accordingly in your listAdapter.